# Destructed object has no Index Signature but other object is fine

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

If I destructure an object and then attempt to pass it into a function with a Record<string, unknown> parameter, I receive an error that the destructured object has no Index Signature. Now, I understand that it doesn't have one but I'm not really sure why it needs one and Typescript can't infer it given it can if I define a new object.

```
declare function example(options: Record<string, unknown>): void;

function doSomething(data: { prop1: string, prop2: string, prop3?: string}) {
  const { prop1, ...rest } = data;
  example(rest); // This doesn't work

  const thisWorks = { prop2: 'string', prop3: undefined }; 
  example(thisWorks); // This does work though, whats the difference?
}
```

Now what I find particularly odd, is if I spread this object into a new one, this compiles fine:

```
declare function example(options: Record<string, unknown>): void;

function doSomethingAgain(data: { prop1: string, prop2: string, prop3?: string}) {
  const { prop1, ...rest } = data;
  example({...rest}); // Now it works?
}
```

So whilst I can jiggle it around to get it to compile, I'd like to undestand a little more what is going on in this scenario.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXxAA8oBbABwhAAoczs8BnALngCVwcZgAeBjGLKgDmAGnhoA1qhwB3VAD4AlCwBuOLMADcAWABQelOnr5gOAMo4SIDAAtBQqsCgYoLAN7wyMWgEYWfAWExL1oAJn9%20e2DvMgBmAH4IwKEAX0V4Nz14eDBGDAzPGJ8xADoyuD54FPgAXngnFx1dbKJSCmoKjEVNeAB6XvgAFTsGepwQBlQAcnyZTgk9LJy8%20FssBgB1edG6jxCycPgpgPsp6NpYljRQREEQYCqmluJySio1ze3uvRTF-V1DJhcCZzJZrHZhABBIRQQSOZyuAr7PzwE5BQphJJRDFxRKoyLCNIZJa5VCVPZFUrlCb5ap1BpQJ4EF7tKhuMolTppHr9eAAOVk8Cws228T%202VJlQ%20WxgEh2SJih2OBKEZxxl3EqBudweKSZrVe1GlXyav10QA)

Comment: I think it's just an [issue with TypeScript](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42021)

Comment: Nice find! Thats definitely the issue. Thanks for your help

Comment: Tip: There is a URL shortener specific for the Typescript playground: https://tsplay-dev.now.sh/ Also, you can link the Playground word instead of showing the link:
`[Playground](https://...)`